# read works from command line, fails from within a script run via nohup

Tags: shell-script

```
read -t 600 -p 'Please specify the format in which you wish to export the file. csv/gz by entering (1/2)?' file_format
```

The above command runs from command line, but when the same is run from a shell script started via `nohup ./script_name with_paramas > out_file` it fails with below error:

```
copy_to_gds.sh: line 26: read: read error: 0: Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: How do you invoke the script?

Comment: I have a test_script.sh within which I invoke copy script with parameter this way sh -x copy_to_gds.sh $var

Comment: Does it work if you use `bash` instead of `sh`? Your `read` call seems to assume `bash`... Also, how do you invoke the wrapper script?

Comment: Does either script _close_ the standard input stream (file descriptor 0)?

Comment: Do you have: <&- or 0<& somewhere in the 26 lines above your error line?  This closes stdin in bash.

Comment: Both bash and sh are giving the same error. I invoke the wrapper script with nohup ./script_name with_paramas > out_file

Comment: I do not have  <&- or 0<& before the line where the error occurs. But I have set -e for exiting when any command fails.

Comment: I think this is a situation in which you will have to show at least the 26 lines of the script leading up to the `read` statement. And if that does not prompt anyone to answer, you may need to show the wrapping script as well.

Comment: Try using TMUX.

Answer (score 2):

This could be reproduced with:

```
$ nohup bash -c 'read var' | cat
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
bash: line 0: read: read error: 0: Bad file descriptor
```

That's what the manpage of `nohup` says (emphasis mine):

> If  standard  input is a terminal, redirect it from an **unreadable file**.

`nohup` does that by opening `/dev/null` in *write only* mode, then redirecting the stdin from it by dup'ing it into fd 0. Thence the `EBADF`(`"Bad file descriptor"`) error -- because your script tries to *read* from a file opened in write only mode:

```
$ read var 0>/dev/null
bash: read: read error: 0: Bad file descriptor
```

It makes little sense to try to get user input via `read` from a script run via `nohup`, so I guess you'll have to rethink your approach.